# Does Laravel Dompdf support subsetting otc fonts?

Tags: laravel, pdf, fonts, subset, dompdf

I've been using vsmoraes dompdf for generating pdf and I use Arial unicode MS (.ttf) which work perfectly with font subsetting enabled.
Since it's not free, I tried to move to Noto Sans.

**But I get a error when I enable font subsetting. .ttf works fine. But not .otc**

```
#message: "Undefined index: glyf"
```

vsmoraes version - 1.0.

Is there any laravel library that I can use which support font subsettings with .otc font type ? 
or is there any suggestions

Comment: I can't speak to your specific question, but I was recently looking at Dompdf vs Snappy ~ and snappy basically has better rendering abilities and the install is only 2 extra steps.  https://github.com/barryvdh has made laravel packages for both if you want to take a look.

Comment: Sorry to answer as a comment but I don't feel qualified enough about DOMPDF or Laravel or PHP to say for sure...it looks like DOMPDF uses a font library that only supports subsetting fonts with `glyf` tables (typically .TTF): https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/issues/10 (the issue is from 2013, but is still open) and that is the same impression I had from the error message. OT* fonts (usually) do not contain a `glyf` table.

Comment: @TarekAdam Thanks. I also though about moving to another library.

Comment: @djangodude Thank you. yes it seems to be the problem with Dompdf. Could yu suggest a suitable library to use for this? or a library that support css fallback rule , so that I can use few fonts to render both chinese and english.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, a bit out of my league there, I just know about fonts :-)