# laravel-dompdf got error "Undefined index: glyf" when enable font subsetting

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I'm trying to generate `pdf` file with `laravel-dompdf` library.

This is my font style I used:

```css
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Hiragino Sans';
            src: url('fonts/Hiragino Sans GB W3.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Hiragino Sans';
            src: url('fonts/Hiragino Sans GB W6.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

This is code in controller:

```php
return PDF::loadView('pdf.presaleorder')->save('test.pdf');
```

Everything works, but `pdf` file generated is too large, greater than `20MB`. I found that I can decrease it size by change `enable_font_subsetting` field in `config/dompdf.php` to `true`.

But when I generate `pdf` file, it thrown error:

```php
 ErrorException  : Undefined index: glyf

  at G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\phenx\php-font-lib\src\FontLib\TrueType\File.php:329
    325|    *
    326|    * @return Table
    327|    */
    328|   public function getTableObject($name) {
  > 329|     return $this->data[$name];
    330|   }
    331| 
    332|   public function setTableObject($name, Table $data) {

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined index: glyf", "G::\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\phenx\php-font-lib\src\FontLib\TrueType\File.php", ["glyf]"])
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\phenx\php-font-lib\src\FontLib\TrueType\File.php:32\Project\29                                                                                                
                                                                                                9        
  2   FontLib\TrueType\File::getTableObject("glyf")
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\phenx\php-font-lib\src\FontLib\TrueType\File.php:2001                                                                                              1        

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

When I added argument `-v`, more trace error showed

```php
 2   FontLib\TrueType\File::getTableObject("glyf")
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\phenx\php-font-lib\src\FontLib\TrueType\File.php:201

  3   FontLib\TrueType\File::setSubset()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\Cpdf.php:1171

  4   Dompdf\Cpdf::processFont()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\Cpdf.php:931

  5   Dompdf\Cpdf::o_font("add")
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\Cpdf.php:3196

  6   Dompdf\Cpdf::output()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php:1213

  7   Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF::output([])
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php:932

  8   Dompdf\Dompdf::output()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-dompdf\src\PDF.php:157

  9   Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::output()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-dompdf\src\PDF.php:167

  10  Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::save("test.pdf")
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\app\Services\OrderService.php:2170

  11  App\Services\OrderService::createOrderPdf()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\app\Console\Commands\CreateOrderPdf.php:41

  12  App\Console\Commands\CreateOrderPdf::handle(Object(App\Services\OrderService))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:32

  13  call_user_func_array()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:32

  14  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:90

  15  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:34

  16  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])    
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:576

  17  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:183

  18  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255

  19  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:170

  20  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1000

  21  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\CreateOrderPdf), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:271

  22  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:147

  23  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:90

  24  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:133

  25  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      G:\Project\Laravel\EventPayment\artisan:37
```

Anyone have solution?

I'm using

```
laravel: 5.8
barryvdh/laravel-dompdf: 0.8.7
dompdf/dompdf: 0.8
windows 10
```

Comment: ```Please use the argument -v to see more details.``` Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace? What version of ```dompdf/dompdf````?

Comment: Also, do you know for sure, that this TTF fonts have ```glyf``` tables? Take a look at the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54461754/3681102

Comment: @JonathanMartins, I've added argument ```-v``` and it show more error trace (I've updated on post) and I'm using ```dompdf/dompdf: 0.8```

Comment: I have a guess that your fonts don't have ```glyf``` tables.

Comment: I'm tried ```dd($this->data)``` in function ```getTableObject``` in  ```\vendor\phenx\php-font-lib\src\FontLib\TrueType\File.php:32```.Unfortunately, it does not contain ```glyf``` field.

Comment: You will be certain of the issue if you could take a font that has these tables and change it by the current ones. The system should not complain.

Comment: Do you know how to determine which font contain ```glyf``` table? For example, with this font ```https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/ms-mincho```, I don't see any thing about ```glyf``` or ```gryph```.

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but the issue is still open: https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/issues/10